# What is the expected number of ball tosses?

Tags: probability

Suppose that we toss balls into four bins until some bin contains three balls. Each toss is independent, and each ball is equally likely to end up in any bin.

What is expected number of ball tosses?

Answer (score 1):

Let your number be $F(0,0,0,0)$.  There are fifteen numbers to work out:
$$F(0,0,0,0)=1+F(1,0,0,0)$$
$$F(1,0,0,0)=1+\frac34F(1,1,0,0)+\frac14F(2,0,0,0)$$
$$F(2,0,0,0)=1+\frac34F(2,1,0,0)$$
and so on.  The final one is $F(2,2,2,2)=1$.